# help having multiple web.config files in a asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, web-config

i have web project that uses resources in a web.config file. it contains everything from db connections to application variables.

i also have a top level folder in my application called /rpt where i store some custom reports pages. i wanted to have a web.config file to contain variations from the main web.config file in this folder such that the files in the /rpt folder can use the connection strings in this "sub" web.config file located in /rpt folder.

so i copied web.config and pasted it into the /rpt folder and deleted everything but the connection string section.

this however did not work as expected. what am i missing?

this is my /rpt web.config file for reference...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <connectionStrings>
        <remove name="PMISConnectionString_prod"/>
        <remove name="PMISConnectionString_test"/>

<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=phedvsv;Initial Catalog=PM;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=IS_User;Password=ll1"/>
        <add name="ConnectionString_test" connectionString="Data Source=phedvsv;Initial Catalog=PM;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=IS_User;Password=ll1"/>
    </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Comment: "this however did not work as expected" - What was expected? Can you post the code?

Comment: this is a copy of my main web.config with everything except connection info stripped out- so that the values from the main config are used and the connection strings are over-written with the ones here in the /rpt .config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one Web.config file per IIS site. So to have another, technically you would need to make the folder /rpt a seperate application within IIS.

Can I ask what you are trying to achieve, your question isn't really clear? What's wrong with adding another connection string to your existing Web.config?

Answer (score 0):

the /rpt folder needs to be made an application in IIS for asp.net to be able to handle a web.config